# Oracle VMWare Linux on AMD Ryzen installation error

Tags: virtual-machine, 64-bit, version, amd-ryzen, oracle-linux

I have an AMD Ryzen 5 2600 and i'm trying to install oracle linux (firstly 7.6, then 8.0) on an Oracle VM VirtualBox.

I've downloaded Oracle Linux 7.6 from the official website (edelivery.oracle.com), this version: V980739-01. But, when i tried to install it in the virtual machine, after chosing install, the virtualbox froze. I tried to do some settings in the Graphics section of the VirtualBox but nothing helped.

Then, i thought it was a problem with this version of linux, so i've downloaded Linux 8.0 from the same website and then, instead of getting frozen, i've got this error from the VirtualBox:

```
This kernel requires an x84-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. 
This processor is not supported in this version of RHEL.
```

I think that this was also the problem with the previous generation (7.6) which i tried to install, but instead of giving me this error, it just froze.

I know that my Ryzen is a 64 bit processor. What is the problem then? What version of linux should i try to download?

In the download page, I have to choose between

```
Linux ARM 64-bit
x86 64 bit
```

I've chosen x86 64 bit and then I had to choose between

```
Oracle Container Services for use with Kubernetes 1.1.9.1, 633.2 MB
Oracle Linux Release 7 Update 6 Boot ISO image for x86 (64 bit), 578.0 MB
Oracle Linux Release 7 Update 6 UEK Boot ISO image for x86 (64 bit), 606.0 MB
Oracle Linux Release 7 Update 6 source DVD 1, 3.5 GB
Oracle Linux Release 7 Update 6 source DVD 2, 4.4 GB
Oracle Linux Release 7 Update 6 for x86 (64 bit), 4.3 GB
Oracle VirtIO Drivers Version for Microsoft Windows 1.1.4, 68.0 MB
```

And I chose the `Oracle Linux Release 7 Update 6 for x86 (64 bit), 4.3 GB` which is this version I mentioned: `V980739-01`.

I've done the same installation on an Intel 6700 processor and everything worked well. So i'm guessing it has something to do with the AMD processor.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Start the computer in BIOS and make sure Hardware Virtualization is enabled (VD-T enabled). That allows 64-bit guest machines to be installed and run. That seems to be the issue here.

Comment: "Linux 8.0" is NOT a thing.  Linux is not a brand.  Do you mean Oracle or RedHat 8.0?  Linux is an operating system produced and made by thousands of people.  RedHat/Oracle are merely one of the many distributions and did not write it.  I am not trying to disrespect you.  I am letting you know that these words make Linux folks that might help you in the future unhappy.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872842/virtualbox-kernel-requires-an-x86-64-cpu-but-only-detected-an-i686-cpu

Comment: Virtualization was enabled. The problem was solved by the comment below. @SeñorCMasMas Considering that I've been talking about oracle linux, it's easy to think that i was still talking about oracle linux and not about some other distribution of linux thx

Comment: i686 is a 32-bit processor.  The application you are running is expected a 64-bit processor.  Since we are dealing with a virtual machine, you installed a 32-bit operating system, which explains the reason the processor is being detected as a i686 processor instead of x86_64 processor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your physical CPU is 64-bit, but the virtualized one is not because you've selected a 32-bit version of Linux when creating the VM.

You can change this in VM settings under *General* section, *Basic* tab. Change *Type* to *Linux*, *Version* to *Oracle (64-bit)*. This will enable 64-bit virtualization.